# How to groupby multiple columns and collapse column with delimiter?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to groupby multiple columns and collapse another column with seperator comma

mydataframe x2

[image]

and i want output like this

[image]

my code is below  can someone how it has to be done

```
x2.groupby(['ID','CUSTOMER_ID','PERIOD'])['CODE'].apply(','.join).reset_index()
```

Comment: Use `agg` instead of `apply` to aggregate the rows with an aggregration of `join` on CODE.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the main issue with your attempt was the current column type, try cast it to string when aggregating,( or as other answers demonstrated better then me, before aggregating),

How about:

```
x2.groupby(['ID','CUSTOMER_ID','PERIOD'], as_index= False)['CODE'].agg(lambda x:','.join(x.astype(str).tolist()))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x2['CODE']=x2['CODE'].astype('string')
x2.groupby(['ID','CUSTOMER_ID','PERIOD'])['CODE'].apply(','.join).reset_index()
```